# Run CSC.exe from command line using Batch File

Tags: c#, csc

I am using the following batch script code to compile c# code but what I see is a black window (csc.exe) flashes and I can not see the exe file created.

```
start /wait C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe /out:aa.exe Program.cs
start aa.exe
pause
```

I want to create the file aa.exe at the same location as Program.cs

Basically what I want is to dynamically compile the code in Program.exe and run it. I am

```
using this following references:  
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

Comment: Here's more info on the subject: [Command-line Building With csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `start` to launch the program, consider `cmd`.  If you use `cmd /K` it should stay open after the command runs, giving you time to inspect the output.

Comment: Yes ! That enabled me to see the error and its working fine now.

Comment: Marking correct answer helps notify others your problem is resolved and not to spend time trouebleshooting. cheers

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to add the references in the command:

```
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\<dotnet_version>\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\<dotnet_version>\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\<dotnet_version>\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\<dotnet_version>\System.dll"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
csc.exe /out:StackBackTraceOrRT_FATAL.exe StackBackTraceOrRT_FATAL.cs
```

Or you want use `[CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx)?

Comment: No I dont want to use any precompiled code. I want to compile on the fly and execute it.

Comment: @AkshayJ: See MSDN what can do CSharpCodeProvider. It is the programmable wrapper against C# Compiler to compile a code from string and generate an assembly, both on disk or in memory. And execute by demand.